# Called function location

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a piece of code in which a specific function is called as:

```
this.m_panel.form.submit(data);
```

I tried to find where actually this function resides but I am unable to find it. How can I find the location of the function definition?

Comment: whithout knowing what this is, theres little chance for us to aid you. Form might be the HTMLFormElement as others have suggested, or it could be something completely different.
If you use a debugger you can put a breakpoint in the line where this call occurs and hover over the objects to find what they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a built-in function of `HTMLFormElement` (Mozilla Developer Network: [DOM > `form.submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/form.submit))

The W3C [defines the method as](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76767676):

> `submit`
>
> Submits the form. It performs the same action as a submit button.
>
> **No Parameters**
> **No Return Value**
> **No Exceptions**

Answer (score 2):

`form.submit` is a built-in function on the `HTMLFormElement` in most DOM implementations. See [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.submit), for instance.